# Fonts not displaying over https

Tags: css, nginx, https

I'm working on[this website](https://burgopak.com) when I turned on the SSL the fonts in the header were replaced with default ones. I've read other threads and have yet to find a solution that works for me.

CSS

```
@font-face {
font-family:"icomoon";
    src:url("../fonts/icomoon.eot?1cffn0");
    src:url("../fonts/icomoon.eot?1cffn0#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("../fonts/icomoon.ttf?1cffn0") format("truetype"),
url("../fonts/icomoon.woff?1cffn0") format("woff"),
url("../fonts/icomoon.svg?1cffn0#icomoon") format("svg");
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}
```

HTML

Nginx server

```
{ listen 443 ssl default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
server_name website.com;
root /home/forge/website.com;

# FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/website-ssl/website.com.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/website-ssl/website.com.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA$
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/website.com/server/*;

client_max_body_size 50M;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on this please.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the browser console if there are any third party url request(.css files) is still http in place of https.

Sample:

issue: **http**://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTXhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff

fix: **https**://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTXhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff

Answer (score 0):

Try this is your css

```
@font-face {
font-family:"icomoon";
    src:url("https://yourdomain.tld/fonts/icomoon.eot?1cffn0");
    src:url("https://yourdomain.tld/fonts/icomoon.eot?1cffn0#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("https://yourdomain.tld/fonts/icomoon.ttf?1cffn0") format("truetype"),
url("https://yourdomain.tld/fonts/icomoon.woff?1cffn0") format("woff"),
url("https://yourdomain.tld/fonts/icomoon.svg?1cffn0#icomoon") format("svg");
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}
```

*Replace* **https://yourdomain.tld** with your domain address...

Comment: That hasn’t worked. The fonts are still getting replaced. I thought it would be something to do with the typography cloud account.

Comment: Still aren't I mean!